# Build Target ios Can't be used when running Unity in batchmode

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, build

I've been trying to automate our iOS builds from Unity using Jenkins. The problem is that when I pass in "-buildTarget ios" to Unity executable, It prints out Build target platform 'iOS' could not be used. without any extra information so that I can know why! I can build successfully using Unity Editor.
I have tried either of following set of arguments and still getting the same error.

```
-batchmode -nographics -projectPath "/Volumes/Data/UnityProject" -logFile 
"/Volumes/Data/UnityProject/Unity/Editor.log" -executeMethod 
PlayerBuilder.BuildSibApp -buildPath ${WORKSPACE} -quit -buildTarget ios

-batchmode -nographics -projectPath "/Volumes/Data/UnityProject" -logFile 
"/Volumes/Data/UnityProject/Unity/Editor.log" -executeMethod 
PlayerBuilder.BuildSibApp -buildPath ${WORKSPACE} -quit -buildTargetGroup ios -buildTarget ios
```

If I omit -nographics, Is produces an error about connecting to window server and quit.
If I omit -buildTarget iOS it produces compile error saying UnityEngine.iOS Could not be found.
By the way I am using MacOS, Unity 5.6.3f1

the log from Unity:

```
COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
-batchmode
-nographics
-projectPath
/Volumes/Data/Pesarkhande-Git
-logFile
/Volumes/Data/Pesarkhande-Git/Unity/Editor.log
-executeMethod
PlayerBuilder.BuildSibApp
-buildPath
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Pesarkhande-iOS-Sibapp
-buildTarget
iOS
-quit
Successfully changed project path to: /Volumes/Data/Pesarkhande-Git
/Volumes/Data/Pesarkhande-Git
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000034 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.033660 seconds
Audio: FMOD Profiler initialized on port 54900
AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.123464 seconds
Build target platform 'iOS' could not be used.
```

And The code that gets executed:

```c#
public static void BuildSibApp()
{

    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    var buildPath = GetCommandLineValue(args, "-buildPath");
    Debug.Log("Build Path: "+buildPath);

     var error = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(EditorBuildSettings.scenes.Where(p => p.enabled).Select(p => p.path).ToArray(),
        buildPath,
        BuildTarget.iOS,
        BuildOptions.SymlinkLibraries | BuildOptions.Il2CPP);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        Debug.LogError(error);
        throw new Exception("Build Failed: \n"+error);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated,Thanks

Comment: I believe that should be iOS not ios.

Comment: @Programmer I changed it to iOS, no luck

Comment: Remove buildTargetGroup  argument from the group

Comment: @Programmer you can see that in first case I'm not passing -buildTargetGroup , still same error

Comment: Ok. I may have another way to do but I want to verify one thing. You said *"I can build successfully using Unity Editor."*. Did you do this with the platform switched to iOS? Can you test again to verify?

Comment: @Programmer , Yes I built successfully when active platform was iOS. I am sure.

Comment: And your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer Unity 5.6.3f1

Comment: There is an error in your code. Hard to track since I don't have the project. You have a script named `PlayerBuilder` and a function named `BuildiOS` inside it. Can you post that `PlayerBuilder` script? *Also mention where you placed that script in your project*

Comment: @Programmer I don't think it's related to my script because Unity exits before reaching it. Anyway, I have modified my question to contain log and my script

Comment: It does especially when there is an error in the script. It is also important if you really want me to be able to reproduce your issue. Last time I asked where you placed that script and never got answer to that. Also, why are you using `PlayerBuilder.BuildiOS` when the actual function name is `PlayerBuilder.BuildSibApp`? I want to help you but I don't have enough info to do so because I cannot reproduce your issue. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Programmer thanks for your time, the script is located inside Editor folder in Assets, Also sorry about the method name, They are the same.